# Console application leaves cmd.exe set size

Tags: c, console, cmd

I have written a console application that sets the size of the console and output buffer. My problem is that after the program ends I cannot resize my cmd.exe window the way I did before. After the program sets the size of the window it retains that size no matter what I do afterwards.

Comment: Are you changing this via registry settings?

Comment: no, I change it in the code of my program.

Comment: what code do you use to change it?

Answer (score 1):

It works for me in C#.

```
namespace CSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Console.WindowHeight = 50;
            System.Console.WindowWidth = 100;
            System.Console.BufferHeight = 6000;
            System.Console.BufferWidth = 100;
        }
    }
}
```

After running the program, I can change the height of the window and make it narrower, just like before.  I can't make it wider, but then I couldn't before, either.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what you mean.  But are you setting the default values for all Cmd consoles when you change the size - That would make new cmd consoles that size too.

Could we have a bit more information about what you mean please.

Answer (score 0):

I believe issue is that he starts program from cmd.exe then size of console is changed. Once exited size of console remains as set in program. What I would sugest is try to save orginal settings and revert them just before exiting program.